# PHP Drop Down List Insert

Tags: php

I have a PHP system where the user will enter details into a form. Once text fields are entered it inserts my data into my database. However, I have drop down lists that do not insert into the database. Could anyone help on this matter as I am a moderate user and have not used PHP a lot. Thank you.

```
InsertDetails.php 
<div class="row">
    <div class="label">Adults 18+</div><!--end label-->
    <div class="input">
    <select name="adultsPlusEight" id="adultsPlusEight" class="detail" name="adultsPlusEight">

      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>         
    </select>
    </div><!--end input--> 
    <div class="context"> Choose how many people to book maximum of 10 per booking</div><!--end context-->              
    </div><!--end row-->


INSERT.PHP<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "loginsystem");
// Check connection
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// Escape user inputs for security
  $fName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['firstname']);
  $sName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['lastname']);
  $telNumb = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['teleNumber']);
  $custEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
  $location = mysqli_real_escape_var_dump($link, $_POST['wlocation']);
  $adultPlus = mysqli_real_escape_integer($link, $_POST['adultsPlusEight']);
  $childPlus = mysqli_real_escape_integer($link, $_POST['childrenPlusTwo']);
  $addinfo = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['additInform']);

// attempt insert query execution
  $sql = "INSERT INTO customerdragon (fName, sName, telNumb, custEmail,
  $location , adultPlus, childPlus, addinfo) VALUES ('$fName', '$sName', '$telNumb', '$custEmail', '$location', '$adultPlus', '$adultPlus', '$childPlus', '$addinfo',  )";
 if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
   echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
   echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>`
```

Comment: remove last comma form query '$addinfo',  )";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);` should have thrown you an SQL error, something you didn't share with us.

Look at this in your VALUES

```
'$addinfo',
          ^
```

- Remove the trailing comma.

> *This is the error I receive: Notice: Undefined index: wlocation in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPLogInSystem\insert1.php on line 14"*

You also have a `$` in `$location` for your column name:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO customerdragon (fName, sName, telNumb, custEmail,  $location
                                                                       ^
```

- Remove the dollar sign. Make sure your column name is indeed called "**location**".

Remember the `$` in `$location` in your column names `(fName, sName, telNumb, custEmail,
  $location , adultPlus, childPlus, addinfo)`?

That needs to read as:

```
(fName, sName, telNumb, custEmail, custLocation, adultPlus, childPlus, addinfo)
```

as per your DB schema.

**Edit:**

Also, you're repeating `'$adultPlus', '$adultPlus',` which would count as a miscount in data entry.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO customerdragon 

(fName, sName, telNumb, custEmail, custLocation, adultPlus, childPlus, addinfo) 

VALUES 

  ('$fName', '$sName', '$telNumb', '$custEmail', '$location', '$adultPlus', '$childPlus', '$addinfo')";
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say what error I had my apologies. This is the error I receive: Notice: Undefined index: wlocation in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPLogInSystem\insert1.php on line 14

Comment: @WhitenaCording ah I see it, remove the `$` for it. I will make an edit.

Comment: @WhitenaCording Please reload my answer.

Comment: Hi thank you for finding the simple errors, I really should try to revise myself when entering code. Thank you. However, when I run the code i get this: Notice: Undefined index: wlocation in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPLogInSystem\insert1.php on line 18
ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO customerdragon (fName, sName, telNumb, custEmail, location , adultPlus, childPlus, addinfo) VALUES ('Bradly', 'Benjamin', '07462516271', 'bradss@hot.com', '', '2', '2', '4', 'I have ashmea'). Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: @WhitenaCording You're welcome. It would have something to do with a form element in your HTML form that may not bear the name attribute or it contains a typo.

Comment: @WhitenaCording Your column name for the emty data, is indeed called `location`?

Comment: This is the code it is referring to, however I cant see any errors or typos: ---------
<div class="row">
        <div class="label">Location</div><!--end label-->
        <div class="input">
  <select name="wlocation" id="wlocation" class="detail" name="wlocation">
          <option value="ystalyfera">ystalyfera</option>
          <option value="Tonmawr">Tonmawr</option>
          <option value="Neath">Neath</option>
        </select>
        </div><!--end input--> 
        <div class="context"> Choose a location e.g Neath</div><!--end context-->              
        </div><!--end row-->

Comment: @WhitenaCording you have 2x name attributes `<select name="wlocation" id="wlocation" class="detail" name="wlocation">` remove one.

Comment: You sir are a genious, almost getting there: Just getting this now.
ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO customerdragon (fName, sName, telNumb, custEmail, custLocation , adultPlus, childPlus, addinfo) VALUES ('bradly', 'Cooper', '02462736172', 'bradlyCooper@live.com', 'Tonmawr', '3', '3', '3', 'I need wheelchair access'). Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: @WhitenaCording remember the `$` in `$location` in `(fName, sName, telNumb, custEmail,
  $location , adultPlus, childPlus, addinfo)`? that needs to read as `(fName, sName, telNumb, custEmail,
  custLocation, adultPlus, childPlus, addinfo)`

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upload an image. However, this is my database structure: i.imgur.com/lkYMo6T.png?1

Comment: @WhitenaCording did you read [my comment just above...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865532/php-drop-down-list-insert#comment47856477_29865550)? `custLocation`  column name. I saw your image earlier. Reload my answer also, another edit was made.

Comment: Hi I found the issue, I had a '$adultPlus', repeating twice that's why it counted 1 more than it should have. Thank you very much for your time really do appreciate it.

Comment: @WhitenaCording You're welcome. Yeah, I noticed your column and values count did not match. I was going to mention that. I've made an edit.

Comment: @WhitenaCording we can close the question now if you could mark it as solved, so others will see that a solution was found.

Comment: I will learn from my silly errors I suppose. How could i add this to the insert Echo part after user has entered the details: <?php else: ?>
<p style="font-size:35px; font-family:verdana; color:#255e67; margin-left:25px; text-align:center;">Thank for booking a paintballing session!</p>
<img src="contact/Images/processing.gif" id="load" style="margin-left:300px;"/></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function()
{
window.location.href='index.php';
}
,5000);
</script>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: @WhitenaCording you'd need to incorporate that where you presently have `echo "Records added successfully.";` however judging by the code you left above, you'd need to do some modifications to get it right. You'd probably need to post a new question if you're having some major difficulties, but in a nutshell; that's basically the logic behind it. `if(DB_entry_success){ show this } else{ show something else }`

Comment: I got you I shall try and figure something out. Thank you very much for helping me that's a big weight of my shoulders now lol. Best wishes to you

Comment: @WhitenaCording You're very much welcome, *cheers* and thanks. The very same to you!

Comment: I was just curious, I want to add validation so a user must enter something to click submit. I would ask another question of the forum but it wont allow me to ask any more questions. Was just wondering if you had time if youd help me figure it out. thanks

Comment: @WhitenaCording `if(!empty($_POST['username'])){ echo "Thank you"; // do something } else{ echo "Enter a name"; // do something else }` or if HTML5, you can just add `required` to your form element(s) input(s).